# SSJS Script Activity Fails to Update DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

**Issue:**

Target DE, **CustomerOrders**, is not updating with the expected output, **OrderId** and **CustomerId** for all Orders. However, the script runs with no errors and logs the **Success** DE and the **Error** DE.

**DE's:**

1. Customers
2. Orders
3. CustomerOrders
4. ErrorLogs
5. SuccessLogs

**SSJS Script Activity:**

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");

var Customers = DataExtension.Init("Customers");
var Orders = DataExtension.Init("Orders");
var CustomerOrders = DataExtension.Init("CustomerOrders");
var ErrorLogs = DataExtension.Init("ErrorLogs");
var SuccessLogs = DataExtension.Init("SuccessLogs");

try {
    var cData = Customers.Rows.Retrieve();
    var oData = Orders.Rows.Retrieve();
        
    for (var i=0; i < oData.length; i++) {
        CustomerOrders.Rows.Add({
            CustomerId: oData[i].CustomerId, 
            OrderId: oData[i].OrderId
        });
    }
    
     SuccessLogs.Rows.Add({
        LogId: GUID(),
        Location: "Customer_Order_Products Automation",
        Description: "Successfully Added rows"
    }) 
} 
catch(e){
    ErrorLogs.Rows.Add({
        LogId: GUID(),
        Location: "Customer_Order_Products Automation",
        Description: Stringify(e)
    })    
}
```

**Question:**

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

**Update:**

Solved by using the External Key in DE Init... However, still not clear were as to how the SuccessLogs and ErrorLogs table were updated without using proper external key but rather the DE name.

Comment: The ending script tag it there, however, somehow not shown in the code snippet.

Comment: are you using the external key of the DE in the init function as stated on this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionFunctions.html

Comment: @EazyE good point and I did not, however, the logs to the SuccessLogs and ErrorLogs DE worked. How could this be explained?

Comment: maybe the successLogs and errorLogs have the same name and customerKey, so it went unnoticed.